# Safari: how to directly jump from 'omnibox' (ie. 'smart search field') to search results (as in Chrome)?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, safari, address-bar

In Chrome, <kbd>TAB</kbd> takes you directly from 'omnibox' to search results. This doesn't seem to be the case in Safari (it takes ~12 <kbd>TAB</kbd>s). Is there any way to remedy this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there *is* a workaround this (annoying behavior) by **hiding the toolbar** (you can leave the 'bookmarks bar' visible). But, now the 'iCloud tabs' aren't accessible anymore: **is there any other way (besides hiding the toolbar) to achieve the sought after Chrome behavior?**

---

Meanwhile, there seems to be a bug in Safari 6.0.1/8536.26.14: while the Toolbar is otherwise hidden, you do get to see it when opening a new (empty) tab ... and if you then click the 'iCloud tabs' button, you get an unexpected behavior: the drop-down menu does show, but is unresponsive (and sometimes it doesn't show at all).