# Safari: how to open a URL while in search mode?

Tags: search, safari, osx-mountain-lion, url

In Chrome you can open a search-highlighted URL with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (and thus obviate the need for using a mouse). How do you do that in Safari (6.0.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way to do that out of the box, but there's some extensions like [Type-To-Navigate](http://dbergey.github.com) that allow selecting links by typing.

> Keep your hands on the keyboard while browsing the web. Type any text that occurs inside a link, and hit return to follow it. ⌘G jumps to the next link containing the text, and ⌘⇧G jumps to the previous. Hit ESC to cancel or exit a focused field.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It does work in Safari 6, although ⌘G doesn't "jump to the next _link_", but rather to any old text (containing the search term).  
Also, is there a way to use this (or other) extension while in the Safari's 'omnibox'? Because this would then solve [my other question](http://superuser.com/q/488787/88320).

Comment: Besides the extension's issue of (not) searching _only_ links: it also doesn't handle one-digit numbers (useful in a forum pagination). So, there really is no built-in way (as in Chrome) to immediately open the URL in Safari's search-mode?